# Haskell first statement static result, changed with the accumulator

Tags: haskell, recursion

I need to understand why this code works:

```
myLength           :: [a] -> Int
myLength []        =  0
myLength (_:xs)    =  1 + myLength xs
```

If I understand the recursion correctly, this function "repeat" this code:

- If the list isn't empty, goes to the next step and do whatever
- but when the list is empty, it stops in the first one and would should return 0

I could understand it if it uses a global variable like n and do something like:

```
myLength [] = n
myLength (_:xs) = (n+1) + myLength xs
```

It doesn't work, but the idea is there, have a value 'n' and increment it in each iteration

Comment: You are but a google query away from understanding how recursion works. There are plenty of wonderful tutorials on this topic, don't let them go to waste.

Comment: In Haskell you can not *increment* variables: *all* variables are *immutable*. So once you set it to some value, it stays that value. This requires some creativity at first, but eventually can result in less bugs in code, since you can always safely assume that the value remains unchanged.

Comment: great thought  @WillemVanOnsem, I write it in the first page of my notes, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you write, it is recursion.

Let's look at the execution of a call in principle:

```
myLength "abc"
```

matches the second overload, so we get

```
1 + myLength "bc"
```

where the recursive call again matches the second overload so that is equal to

```
1 + 1 + myLength "c"
```

which is equal to

```
1 + 1 + 1 + myLength ""
```

and we have reached the base case

```
myLength [] = 0
```

so the recursion terminates and the result is

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 0
```

Note that when the base case "returns 0" that is the result for *that particular application of the function*, not the result of the initial call.

A key here is that each application of a function yields a value. 
That is, you don't "go to the next step and do whatever", you add one to the length of the tail (which is a value). Therefore you don't need some global state (In fact, it would only complicate things).

Also, please note that there is no *assignment* involved, the functions define equalities and thus the left-hand side can be replaced by the right-hand side.